# How disable triangulation mode on mapview in gluon?

Tags: dictionary, javafx, points, gluon

I'm using MapView component of Gluon and when I add some points on the map, I see the points and a kind of "triangulation" across the points (in red).
Is there a way to disable this thing?

[image]

I solved, I had this lines in costructor:

```
  polygon = new Polygon();
  polygon.setStroke(Color.RED);
  polygon.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5));
  this.getChildren().add(polygon);
```

Now I set the color of stroke and fill at transparent and the polygon becomes invisible.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot and how you add the points to the map?

Comment: I solved, I set the color of stroke and fill at transparent and the polygon became invisible.

Comment: Actually you can use any JavaFX node, not only a polygon. See [demo sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/maps/tree/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/maps/demo).